# Making a player "bump" from an enemy/hazard in GML

Tags: collision, gml, game-maker-studio-2

I've been making an RPG with Game Maker Studio 2.0 for my kids and have got stuck on one major issue. Collisons with enemies and hazards. A general collison would cause the game to keep registering colisions and cause the player to immediately die. I am trying to replace my premilinary solution of warping the player to one safe spot in each room, which is not ideal-- so I created a few scripts to "bump" the player to safe area depending on which direction/side of enemy the player collided. I am not a great programmer and I tend to make code that is over-complicated. It almost works-- it just bumps the player in the same direction everytime-- to the left of the enemy. If anyone could examine these scripts and give me some hints, it would be much appreciated.

Code in enemy object for collsion with player:

```
var get_enemy_loc, player_side, col

get_enemy_loc = scr_enemy_pos(obj_scorpion)
player_side = scr_player_orient(get_enemy_loc[0],get_enemy_loc[1],obj_player.x,obj_player.y)
col = scr_check_block(get_enemy_loc[0],get_enemy_loc[1])

show_debug_message("Player X")
show_debug_message(obj_player.x)
show_debug_message("Player Y")
show_debug_message(obj_player.y)
show_debug_message("Enemy X")
show_debug_message(get_enemy_loc[0])
show_debug_message("Enemy Y")
show_debug_message(get_enemy_loc[1])

if player_side[0] = true and col[2] = false{
    scr_shift_player(1)
}
    else
        if col[0] = false{
            scr_shift_player(4)
        }
        else{
            if col[3] = false{
                scr_shift_player(3)
            }
            else{
                scr_shift_player(2)
            }   
}
 if player_side[1] = true and col[2] = false{
     scr_shift_player(1)
 }
    else
        if col[0] = false{
            scr_shift_player(4)
        }
        else{
            if col[1] = false{
                scr_shift_player(2)
            }
            else{
                scr_shift_player(3)
            }
        }
        
if player_side[2] = true and col[3] = false{
    scr_shift_player(3)
}
    else
        if col[0] = false{
            scr_shift_player(4)
        }
        else{
            if col[2] = false{
                scr_shift_player(1)
            }
            else{
                scr_shift_player(2)
            }
        }

if player_side[3] = true and col[3] = false{
    scr_shift_player(3)
}
    else
        if col[0] = false{
            scr_shift_player(4)
        }
        else{
            if col[1] = false{
                scr_shift_player(2)
            }
            else{
                scr_shift_player(1)
            }
        }
```

Script for enemy position:

```
function scr_enemy_pos(enemy_int){
var enemy_pos;
enemy_pos[0] = enemy_int.x;
enemy_pos[1] = enemy_int.y;
return enemy_pos;
}
```

Script for checking for blocking objects:

```
function scr_check_block(enemy_x,enemy_y){
var left_col, right_col, up_col, down_col;
var group;
check_left = enemy_x - 100
check_right = enemy_x + 100
check_up = enemy_y + 100
check_down = enemy_y - 100
if position_empty(check_left,enemy_y){
    left_col = false}
    else {
        left_col = true
    }
if position_empty(check_right,enemy_x){
    right_col = false
    }
    else {
        right_col = true
    }
if position_empty(enemy_x,check_up){
    up_col = false
}
    else {
        up_col = true
    }
if position_empty(enemy_x,check_down){
    down_col = false
}
    else {
        down_col = false
    }
group[0] = left_col
group[1] = right_col
group[2] = up_col
group[3] = down_col

return group
}
```

Script for checking players orientation on collision:

```
function scr_player_orient(enemy_x,enemy_y,player_x,player_y){
    var ne, se, nw, sw;
    ne = false
    se = false
    nw = false
    sw = false
    var comb
    if enemy_x <= player_x and enemy_y <= player_y{
        nw = true
    }
    else{
        nw = false
    }
    if enemy_x > player_x and enemy_y <= player_y{
        ne = true
    }
    else{
        ne = false
    }
    if enemy_x <= player_x and enemy_y > player_y{
        sw = true
    }
    else{
        sw = false
    }
    if enemy_x > player_x and enemy_y > player_y{
        se = true
    }
    else{
        se = false
    }
    comb[0] = nw
    comb[1] = ne
    comb[2] = sw
    comb[3] = se
    
    return comb;
}
```

Script for executing player "bump":

```
function scr_shift_player(dir){
if dir = 1{
    obj_player.y = obj_player.y - 20
    }
if dir = 2{
    obj_player.x = obj_player.x + 20
    }
if dir = 3{
    obj_player.y = obj_player.y + 20
    }
if dir = 4{
    obj_player.x = obj_player.x - 20
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question. I solved this problem by updtating the collsion code and
using a different script. I threw out scr_player_orient and replaced it with scr_player_dir using the following code.

Updated collsion code in enemy object

```
ar get_enemy_loc, player_side, col

get_enemy_loc = scr_enemy_pos(obj_scorpion)
player_side = scr_player_dir(get_enemy_loc[0],get_enemy_loc[1])
col = scr_check_block(get_enemy_loc[0],get_enemy_loc[1])

show_debug_message("Player X")
show_debug_message(obj_player.x)
show_debug_message("Player Y")
show_debug_message(obj_player.y)
show_debug_message("Enemy X")
show_debug_message(get_enemy_loc[0])
show_debug_message("Enemy Y")
show_debug_message(get_enemy_loc[1])

if player_side[0] = true and col[1] = false{
        scr_shift_player(2)
    }
    else{
        scr_shift_player(4)
    }
    
if player_side[1] = true and col[0] = false{
        scr_shift_player(4)
    }
    else{
        scr_shift_player(2)
    }

if player_side[2] = true and col[2] = false{
        scr_shift_player(2)
    }
    else{
        scr_shift_player(3)
    }

if player_side[3] = true and col[3] = false{
        scr_shift_player(3)
    }
    else{
        scr_shift_player(2)
    }
```

And used this new script -- scr_player_dir

```
function scr_player_dir(enemy_x, enemy_y){
    var left,right,up,down,comb
    left = false
    right = false
    down = false
    up = false
    if enemy_x < obj_player.x{
        right = true && left = false
        }
    else{
        right = false && left = true
    }
    
    if enemy_y < obj_player.x{
        down = true && up = false
    }
    else{
        down = false && up = true
    }
    comb[0] = right
    comb[1] = left
    comb[2] = up
    comb[3] = down
    
    return comb
}
```

I hope this helps someone with the same problem